# how to map an attributre in elasticsearch?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

i need to index a json to Elasticsearch.

```
 PUT json/try/1
    {
        "name":"rajesh",
        "emp id":236947,
"dob":"28-02-1989"
}
```

So for this i need to map fields like dob to date format dd-mm-yyyy. Basically i understand that before indexing this data to elasticsearch i need to map these attributes.I am using sense to index and map these data. i try

```
PUT /json/try/_mapping
        {
            "dob": {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dd-mm-yyyy"}
        }
```

This syntax is working But while indexing the data as above mentioned syntax still not able to recognize fields dob? What i am missing. Could anyone please guide...
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the date formats suggested by elasticsearch  [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

Now a simple date mapping would be:

```
PUT json/try/_mapping
{
    "try":{
        "properties": {
            "dob":{
                "type": "date"
                , "format": "date"
             }
         }
     }
 }`
```

Where date is yyyy-MM-dd format